# PHP syntax wrong? Outputting Resource id #3

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
if (!$link) {
die('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('mysql', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}
$query = sprintf("SELECT church_id FROM hours 
         WHERE day_of_week = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%w') AND 
         CURTIME() BETWEEN open_time AND close_time",
    mysql_real_escape_string($day_of_week),
    mysql_real_escape_string($open_time),
    mysql_real_escape_string($close_time));
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    $message = 'Invalid query: ' .mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' .$query;
    die($message);
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['shop_id'];
}

mysql_free_result($result);
echo "end";
?>
```

I know SQL query works by copying/pasting into phpmyadmin. I want the script to just output a shop_id or series of shop_ids. Right now it outputs Resource id #3. I looked up how to fix it and mysql_fetch_array was supposed to be the answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should post what you are seeing that looks wrong -- crash result, output, etc. Also please note **mysql is deprecated and new code should be written to mysqli**

Comment: ... or PDO. See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: 1) Where does `$day_of_week` come from? 2) Your `sprintf` string has only one placeholder yet you are passing three values? 3) You `SELECT church_id` yet try to echo `shop_id` 4) That output is not possible from the code above. At no point are you displaying anything that could be a resource

Comment: Resource id #3 means your query is correct. It's just that your query is lacking... the shop_id row. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking over your query and I only see you selecting church_id and you want to output shop_id, you should include that in your select like so:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT church_id, shop_id FROM hours WHERE day_of_week = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%w') AND CURTIME() BETWEEN open_time AND close_time",
    mysql_real_escape_string($day_of_week),
    mysql_real_escape_string($open_time),
    mysql_real_escape_string($close_time));
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: There are still 3 parameters being passed to sprintf and only one placeholder. This wouldn't cause it to fail, but it's still an error in the code you have in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems here, the first of which is that you are using the *mysql* extension which is unmaintained and officially deprecated (due to be removed). I suggest you try *mysqli*...

```
$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'mysql');
if ($link->errno) {
    throw new Exception($link->error, $link->errno);
}
```

Whilst you've done a commendable job of securing your query, you really should be using the better tools available in *mysqli*, notably [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)...

```
$stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT church_id FROM hours 
     WHERE day_of_week = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), ?) AND 
     CURTIME() BETWEEN open_time AND close_time');
if (!$stmt) {
    throw new Exception($link->error, $link->errno);
}
$stmt->bindParam('s', $day_of_week); // assuming $day_of_week is properly defined
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    throw new Exception($stmt->error, $stmt->errno);
}
```

Fetching data from a *mysqli* prepared statement is a little different to the old `mysql_fetch_array` however it's not difficult. One way is to use *result binding*

```
$stmt->bind_result($church_id);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $church_id;
}
```